# Can I prevent pip from downgrading packages implicitly?

Tags: python, django, pip, downgrade

I have Django 1.10.5 installed in my python virtual environment.

When I install djblets into my virtualenv with `pip install djblets`, unfortunately, Django is being implicitly downgraded to version 1.8.17 along the way. This breaks my environment.

Is there something I could have done to prevent this? I certainly wasn't asked whether I'm okay with the downgrade. But I really should have.

djblets version 0.9.6 doesn't even install because it depends on Pillow, which refuses to build. It's all just broken and kills my environment along the way because uninstalling comes first.

All I can think about is trying the installation in a separate, but identical, virtual environment and seeing what happens. Like a dry-run.

Now I have to install my environment from scratch. Am I missing something, or is this just the way it is?

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is in newer (ok, since long long ago, pip 7.1) pip versions, although it's not exactly documented like that:

[Pip constraint files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files)

So the following commands (you need to run them in your project directory and potentially customize them):

```
pip freeze | grep == | sed 's/==/>=/' >constraints.txt
pip install -c constraints.txt whatever-you-want-to-install
```

will install whatever-you-want-to-install without downgrading anything. Caveat: whatever-you-want-to-install actually requires a lower version "sometoy", whatever-you-want-to-install will be broken, at least in relation to it's usage of "sometoy".

In some cases the breakage might be acceptable (e.g. it happens in some optional areas of the package that you do not use), in some cases no actual breakage might happen (e.g. the downgrade causing version constraint is not needed anymore), in some cases really bad things will happen and they are on you.

Comment: isn't sed alone necessary without grep?

Comment: Well, sed alone would have a different meaning. grep selects the packages that have a specific version selected only. OTOH, it's possible that sed can be used to "grep" out only some lines too, but then I prefer to use the simplest tool at hand.

Another CAVEAT: pip has changed fundamentally its behaviour since Oct/Nov 2020. so take care with anything you read here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install both packages **at the same time** (with only one command) and specify the **number version** of the package

```
pip install django==1.10.5 djblets
```

As a rule of thumb, rather than installing your packages one-by-one, I'd recommand using a `requirements.txt` file.

For your example, your file `requirements.txt` will have (at least):

```
django==1.10.5
djblets==1.0.2
```

Then, you can install all packages in one time using the option [`[--requirements, -r]`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-r) of `pip`:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Why?**

Unless told excplicitly so, `pip` will try to install the best dependencies for a given module (the ones describe in the package itself) and that could even **downgrade** a package!

Oftentimes, you will not have a choice to downgrade NOR upgrade a package to make it work. That's why it is very important to put a **version number** in each packages you need in order to avoid regression!

**Tips**

- You can find the version number of a package in [PyPI - the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)
- Or install automatically the latest version using the option [`[-U, --upgrade]`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-u) of `pip`:

  ```
  pip install -U django==1.10.5 djblets
  ```

(OK because `update` option works only with packages having unspecified version number)

- You can also install a package with no dependencies at all with option [`[--no-deps]`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-deps) of `pip`:

  ```
  pip install --no-deps djblets
  ```

But this method is only valid if you have already all the dependencies installed.

**Bonus**

To answer the question you did not ask, you can make a "snapshot" of all your packages install if you are scared of doing wrong manipulations, using [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/)

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: If `djblets` depends on `django==1.8.17`, this will probably break `djblets` because `django==1.10.5` will be forcibly installed. There isn't any solution to this specific problem besides having both your code and `djblets` work on a single version of Django.

Comment: @Blender yes I totaly agree with you! To be honest I did not even tried to installed both packages because I'm not currently with my "dev-pc". It just happend that I had downgrading problems with pip today at work that I was able to fix using this technique (it was a chaining several requirements.txt files, but it is similar). Anyhow: I just wanted to have a "generic solution" for this kind of problems. Because I did not found any on SO. Even if it didn't solve this very problem, I think it could be useful to other peoples. But maybe I should have created my own question. Nice remark though.